# What is the Family History of Daruka, the Reputed Charioteer of Lord Krishna?

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavata-purana, harivamsa, brahma-vaivarta-purana, garga-samhita

I researched a lot about Daruka, the famous and most trusted charioteer of Lord Krishna. His name appears in ***Harivamsha Puran, Vishnu Parva, Chapter 22***, mentioned before comparatively more important Kansa's nine brothers. King Kansa called for a late-night meeting with his chiefs and decided to invite Lord Krishna to get him killed as and when possible.
I wonder how this Daruka, who attained a remarkable status later became so crucial that Lord Krishna took him with 18 leading Yadava families to Dwarka and appointed him his chief charioteer. This Daruka is mentioned in many other religious texts like Bhagavatam, Mahabharata, Garga Samhita, Harivamsha Puran, Brahmavaivart Purana, and even Vishnu Purana, but not after the funeral of Lord Krishna's family or further later when the remaining of Yaduvamsi's re migrated to Indraprastha and the great-grandson of Lord Krishna, Vajra Nabha was appointed as the King of Mathura.
My humble question is who were Daruka's parents? Why he was so trusted? What made him so important that he was appointed the chief charioteer even though he was trusted by Kamsa himself as well.

Comment: it was Dāruka himself who informed Arjuna, that Yaduvaṁśa had perished. Kr̥ṣṇa gave instructions to him before meditating to go to Arjuna in Mausala Parva in Mahābhārata.
This instance is also present in the Viṣṇu Purāṇa. 
So, he most likely survived along with the other Yādavas.

Comment: As for his family history, I am not familiar with it sadly. But as Kr̥ṣṇa told him and gave him such a task, according to the epic, it's logical that he survived, since he was asked to go with Arjuna and others, and leave Dvāraka and he did accompany him. What happened to him later after the migration, is also not known as you said.
Perhaps his family history is not even there. As for Kr̥ṣṇa keeping a man under Kaṁsa is not something so unique, because not all people under Kaṁsa were like him.

Comment: His skill and position is what made him important according to me to Kr̥ṣṇa. Royalty values someone who is skillful and loyal, and he was both. Plus, he was not of those who rejected Kr̥ṣṇa after the fall of Kaṁsa.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answerbut please read my questions again. I asked (1) Who were Daruka's parents? (2) Why he was so trusted that he was appointed the chief charioteer even though he was trusted by Kamsa himself as well. As mentioned in Harivamsha Puran, Vishnu Parva, Chapter 22, his name mentioned before many of King Kamsa's own brothers and even the Maha Mantri. Why?

Comment: I have already read the question,  I wasn't answering in the comments above, but just giving some of my thoughts in the comments Since, I don't know the answers to your questions, I didn't answer them. I gave my own personal opinion of (2), but I don't know anything about (1).  I hope someone can come up with good answers for those.